trigger amplify lambda function in react native app
So I created a function through the amplify cli amplify add function , I can succesfully run this function in the aws console in lambda. Now I want to be able to invoke this function when a user clicks a button for example.
amplify
   - backend
       -function
           - my_function
               - src
                   - index.js
src
   - components
        - my_component
             - screen_which_will_use_the_function

Now I think it would be weird if i have to invoke the lambda function as someone explains in this post as the function code is already written in my codebase.
Also I find the documentation not so clear and can't find an example of someone using this and executing the function in an onPress event. All help is greatly adviced on this topic!
